# how to delete a row with an empty column in android database?

Tags: android, sql, database

That is a straight forward question.

What I already did:

```
sql.delete(TBL_ITEMS, KEY_TOTAL_AMOUNT + "=" + "", null);
```

or

```
sql.delete(TBL_ITEMS, KEY_TOTAL_AMOUNT + "=" + null, null);
```

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can give it a try :

```
sql.delete(TBL_ITEMS, KEY_TOTAL_AMOUNT + " IS NULL", null);
```

Comment: Wow! I did not know that is possible. Thank you